# Need to display website neatly for mobile devices and smaller screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having trouble figuring out how to display my digital portfolio website neatly on smaller screen sizes. I have no idea how. I will list my code for my blog and projects pages as well as my stylesheet. I don't care how it looks on smaller screens as long as it looks neat and things don't overlap.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <header>
        <div class="imageholder">
           <img src="images/headingphoto1.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto2.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto3.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto4.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto5.jpg" class="headerimg">
        </div>
     </header>
     <article>
        <div id="blogHeader">
           <h1>A Bear and His Thoughts</h1>
           <p>A Blog by Jared "Bear" VanOeffelen</p>
        </div>
        <div id="blogContent">
           <div class="post">
              <h2>Who is Bear?</h2>
              <h3 class="date">May 17, 2018</h3>
              <p>Bear is a nickname that I orignally received from my second grade teacher. Years later my sister and mother started calling me it as well. I originally hated it, but it has now kinda grown on me.</p>
              <p>Anyways, this is my blog and I hope to update it as often as possible with tons of content. I will be posting a lot of stuff relating to Web Development as well as updates on my projects that I will be working on. I might even add some stuff about my hobbies and other things that peak my interest</p>
              <p>Take a look around and I hope you enjoy your visit into the world of, "A Bear and His Thoughts!"</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </article>
     <aside>
        <img src="images/profilephoto.jpg">
        <h3 class="title">Jared VanOeffelen</h3>
        <nav class="sitenavigation">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
     </aside>
     <footer>
        <p>Jared VanOeffelen &#8226; Web Developer</p>
        <p>Grand Rapids, Michigan</p>
        <p>jvanoeffelen18@gmail.com &#8226; (616)-633-2391</p>
     </footer>
  </div>
```

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <header>
        <div class="imageholder">
           <img src="images/headingphoto1.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto2.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto3.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto4.jpg" class="headerimg">
           <img src="images/headingphoto5.jpg" class="headerimg">
        </div>
     </header>
     <article>
        <div class="project">
           <section class="info">
              <h2>Project title &amp; link</h2>
              <p>Description of the project</p>
           </section>
           <section class="image">
              <!--for image of the project-->
           </section>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
           <section class="info">
              <h2>Project title &amp; link</h2>
              <p>Description of the project</p>
           </section>
           <section class="image">
              <!--for image of the project-->
           </section>
        </div>
        <div class="project">
           <section class="info">
              <h2>Project title &amp; link</h2>
              <p>Description of the project</p>
           </section>
           <section class="image">
              <!--for image of the project-->
           </section>
        </div>
     </article>
     <aside>
        <img src="images/profilephoto.jpg">
        <h3 class="title">Jared VanOeffelen</h3>
        <nav class="sitenavigation">
           <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
     </aside>
     <footer>
        <p>Jared VanOeffelen &#8226; Web Developer</p>
        <p>Grand Rapids, Michigan</p>
        <p>jvanoeffelen18@gmail.com &#8226; (616)-633-2391</p>
     </footer>
  </div>
```

```
/* reset styles section */
html {
   font-size: 16px;
}
body {
   background-color: black;
}
a, article, aside, body, div, embed, footer, header, h1, h2, h3, li, nav, 
object, p, section, ul {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;   
}
/* body and page container */
.container {
   max-width: 85%;
   background-color: beige;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
}
/* headings */
h1 {
   padding: 0.4 0.6em;
   font-size: 3.2em;
   text-align: center;
   color: DodgerBlue;
}
h2 {
   padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   text-align: center;
}
h2:after {
   content: ' ';
   display: block;
   border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
   border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
h3 {
   padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
   font-size: 1.8em;
}
/* header images section */
.imageholder {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
.headerimg {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 19%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
/* main content */
article {
   width: 83%;
   float: right;
   padding: 1em 0;
}
article p {
   padding: 0 1em 1em;
   font-size: 1.4em;
}
.resume {
   width: 95%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
/* blog section */
#blogHeader {
   background-color: #cccccc;
   height: 90px;
   width: 98%;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   display: block;
}
.post {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   width: 97%;
   display: block;
}
.date {
   font-size: 1.6em;
   padding: 0 1em 1em;
   font-weight: bold;
}
/* projects container section */
.info {
   float: left;
   width: 62%;
   min-height: 300px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   margin-bottom: 5px;   
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
.image {
   float: right;
   width: 30%;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   min-height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid #cccccc;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-right: 30px;
}
/* sidebar */
aside {
   padding: 1em 0;
   background-color: DodgerBlue;
   float: left;
   width: 16%;
   text-align: center;
}
aside p {
   padding: 0.4em 0;
   margin: 0 0 0.6em;
   color: FloralWhite;
}
.title {
   padding: 0.4em 0;
   margin: 0 0 0.6em;
   color: FloralWhite;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 2em;
}
aside img {
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
}
nav.sitenavigation {
   text-align: center;
}
nav.sitenavigation ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}
nav.sitenavigation li {
   margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   line-height: 1.5em;
}
a {
   color: FloralWhite;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:hover, nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
   color: black;
}
/* footer section */
footer {
   padding: 0.6em;
   color: FloralWhite;
   background-color: DodgerBlue;
   text-align: center;
   clear: right;
}
footer p {
   margin: 0.4em;
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're opposed to using a framework like skeleton or bootstrap? I see a handful of floats in your CSS, but few clear's. When you float an element, you pull it out of the DOM flow. So you end up with weird overlaps happening, and the only way to fix them is to clear the float. Otherwise, set up a jsfiddle or codepen with a function copy of these pages for better assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your container a fixed width and change your viewport settings to zoom out and display the whole site on mobile.

```css
/* reset styles section */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

a,
article,
aside,
body,
div,
embed,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3,
li,
nav,
object,
p,
section,
ul {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* body and page container */

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}


/* headings */

h1 {
  padding: 0.4 0.6em;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  text-align: center;
  color: DodgerBlue;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

h2:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

h3 {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}


/* header images section */

.imageholder {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerimg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* main content */

article {
  width: 83%;
  float: right;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

article p {
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.resume {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* blog section */

#blogHeader {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 90px;
  width: 98%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.post {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 97%;
  display: block;
}

.date {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* projects container section */

.info {
  float: left;
  width: 62%;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.image {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}


/* sidebar */

aside {
  padding: 1em 0;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  float: left;
  width: 16%;
  text-align: center;
}

aside p {
  padding: 0.4em 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.6em;
  color: FloralWhite;
}

.title {
  padding: 0.4em 0;
  margin: 0 0 0.6em;
  color: FloralWhite;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

aside img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

nav.sitenavigation {
  text-align: center;
}

nav.sitenavigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.sitenavigation li {
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: FloralWhite;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:hover,
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
  color: black;
}


/* footer section */

footer {
  padding: 0.6em;
  color: FloralWhite;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  text-align: center;
  clear: right;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0.4em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="imageholder">
        <img src="images/headingphoto1.jpg" class="headerimg">
        <img src="images/headingphoto2.jpg" class="headerimg">
        <img src="images/headingphoto3.jpg" class="headerimg">
        <img src="images/headingphoto4.jpg" class="headerimg">
        <img src="images/headingphoto5.jpg" class="headerimg">
      </div>
    </header>
    <article>
      <div id="blogHeader">
        <h1>A Bear and His Thoughts</h1>
        <p>A Blog by Jared "Bear" VanOeffelen</p>
      </div>
      <div id="blogContent">
        <div class="post">
          <h2>Who is Bear?</h2>
          <h3 class="date">May 17, 2018</h3>
          <p>Bear is a nickname that I orignally received from my second grade teacher. Years later my sister and mother started calling me it as well. I originally hated it, but it has now kinda grown on me.</p>
          <p>Anyways, this is my blog and I hope to update it as often as possible with tons of content. I will be posting a lot of stuff relating to Web Development as well as updates on my projects that I will be working on. I might even add some stuff
            about my hobbies and other things that peak my interest</p>
          <p>Take a look around and I hope you enjoy your visit into the world of, "A Bear and His Thoughts!"</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
    <aside>
      <img src="images/profilephoto.jpg">
      <h3 class="title">Jared VanOeffelen</h3>
      <nav class="sitenavigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
    <footer>
      <p>Jared VanOeffelen &#8226; Web Developer</p>
      <p>Grand Rapids, Michigan</p>
      <p>jvanoeffelen18@gmail.com &#8226; (616)-633-2391</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```